# Почему не перерисовывается изображение?

Tags: java

Почему по клику кнопки не перерисовывается изображение? Рисуется только при запуске.

```
import java.awt.;
import java.awt.geom.;
import java.awt.event.;
import java.awt.font.TextLayout;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import javax.swing.;
import java.util.*;

public class ElDevice extends JPanel {
    int lampsCount;
    int w1, h1, lw=50, lh=50;
    boolean workl=false;
    public void init(int lampsCount, int lw,int lh, int w1, int h1, boolean workl) {
        this.lampsCount=lampsCount;
        this.lw=lw;
        this.lh=lh;
        this.w1=h1;
        this.w1=w1;
        this.h1=h1;
        this.workl=workl;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Dimension d = getSize();
        g2.setBackground(getBackground());
        g2.clearRect(0, 0, d.width, d.height);
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        drawDemo(d.width, d.height, g2, w1, h1, lw, lh, lampsCount, workl);
    }

    public void drawDemo(int w, int h, Graphics2D g2,int w1,int h1,int lw,int lh,
                         int lampsCount,boolean workl) {
        g2.setColor(Color.black);
        g2.drawRect(0, 0, w1, h1);
        for(int i=0; i<lampsCount; i++) {
            g2.drawOval(i*10, 10, lw, lh);
            if(workl == true) {
                for(int j=0; i<lampsCount; j++) {
                    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                    g2.fillOval(1, 10, lw, lh);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

import java.awt.;
import java.awt.event.;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Main {
    static int TF_LEFT_COORD=200, TF_RIGHT_COORD=50;
    public static void main(String[] args) { //Создание Обектов final JFrame form = new JFrame("Лаба 3 Вывод електрического устройства"); final JButton button1 = new JButton("Показать Устройство"); // form.setLayout(null); form.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); form.setSize(400, 400); form.setLayout(null); form.setVisible(true);
        //      form.setResizable(false);
        //Указание координат
        final JCheckBox check1 = new JCheckBox();
        final JTextField edit1 = new JTextField("3");
        final JTextField edit2 = new JTextField("10");
        final JTextField edit3 = new JTextField("20");
        final JTextField edit4 = new JTextField("50");
        final JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Количество Лампочек:");
        final JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Радиус Лампочки:");
        final JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Высота Устройства:");
        final JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Длина Устройства:");
        final JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Включено:");
        //

        button1.setBounds(20, 20, 200, 30);
        //
        // Отображение

        form.getContentPane().add(button1);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                form.getContentPane().add(button1).setVisible(false);
                final JButton paintLamp = new JButton("Показать Устройство");

                //
                paintLamp.setBounds(150, 130, 300, 20);
                label1.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 10, 300, 20);
                edit1.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 10, 100, 20);
                edit2.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 30, 100, 20);
                edit3.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 70, 100, 20);
                edit4.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 90, 100, 20);
                label2.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 30, 300, 20);
                label5.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 50, 300, 20);
                check1.setBounds(230, 50, 300, 20);
                label3.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 70, 200, 20);
                label4.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 90, 200, 20);

                //
                form.getContentPane().add(paintLamp);
                form.getContentPane().add(edit1);
                form.getContentPane().add(label3);
                form.getContentPane().add(label4);
                form.getContentPane().add(edit2);
                form.getContentPane().add(label1);
                form.getContentPane().add(label2);
                form.getContentPane().add(check1);
                form.getContentPane().add(edit3);
                form.getContentPane().add(label5);
                form.getContentPane().add(edit4);

                //
                form.getContentPane().setVisible(false);
                form.getContentPane().setVisible(true);

                paintLamp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        final ElDevice dev = new ElDevice();
                        dev.init(Integer.parseInt(edit1.getText()), Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText()),
                                 Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText()), Integer.parseInt(edit3.getText())
                                 , Integer.parseInt(edit4.getText()), check1.isSelected());
                        dev.setBounds(150, 150, 4000, 4000);
                        form.getContentPane().add(dev).setVisible(false);
                        form.getContentPane().add(dev).setVisible(true);
                    }
                });

            }

        });

    }

}
```

Comment: почитайте пожалуйста про паттерн MVC

Comment: Это адская жуть. Именно поэтому это никогда не заработает как надо. И не дай бог вы передумаете в отношении функционала..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно удалять предыдущую панель. Попробуйте так:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        ElDevice dev;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            form.getContentPane().add(button1).setVisible(false);
            JButton paintLamp = new JButton("Показать Устройство");

            paintLamp.setBounds(150, 130, 300, 20);
            label1.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 10, 300, 20);
            edit1.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 10, 100, 20);
            edit2.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 30, 100, 20);
            edit3.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 70, 100, 20);
            edit4.setBounds(TF_LEFT_COORD, 90, 100, 20);
            label2.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 30, 300, 20);
            label5.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 50, 300, 20);
            check1.setBounds(230, 50, 300, 20);
            label3.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 70, 200, 20);
            label4.setBounds(TF_RIGHT_COORD, 90, 200, 20);

            //
            form.getContentPane().add(paintLamp);
            form.getContentPane().add(edit1);
            form.getContentPane().add(label3);
            form.getContentPane().add(label4);
            form.getContentPane().add(edit2);
            form.getContentPane().add(label1);
            form.getContentPane().add(label2);
            form.getContentPane().add(check1);
            form.getContentPane().add(edit3);
            form.getContentPane().add(label5);
            form.getContentPane().add(edit4);

            //
            form.getContentPane().setVisible(false);
            form.getContentPane().setVisible(true);

            paintLamp.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    try{
                    form.remove(dev);
                    }finally{
                    dev = new ElDevice();
                    dev.init(Integer.parseInt(edit1.getText()), Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText()),
                             Integer.parseInt(edit2.getText()), Integer.parseInt(edit3.getText())
                             , Integer.parseInt(edit4.getText()), check1.isSelected());
                    dev.setBounds(150, 150, 4000, 4000);
                    form.getContentPane().add(dev).setVisible(false);
                    form.getContentPane().add(dev).setVisible(true);

                    }
                }
            });

        }

    });
```

Или не создавать новый объект .. а изменять его параметры через getter,setters

```
for(int j=0; i<lampsCount; j++) {
                g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                g2.fillOval(1, 10, lw, lh);
            }
```

посмотри внимательно на этот цикл..вместа i нада j

Comment: пробывал, но происходит зависание ... и поэтому решил обратится сюда

Answer (score 0):

Сразу предупрежу - твой код не смотрел, 
но на вскидку у тебя нет нигде вызова .repaint() для панели что нужно перерисовать;
добавь его в конец тела слушателя